# Multiple results handling in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to Return all the users in a table who have a specific badge number. The catch is that the badges are 1-10, and the users that have the higher badges also have the previous ones. So the userID shows up multiple times for each badgeID (ex. userID:1 has badge 5,4,3,2,1.)

So how can i write my query to find all my userID's in badge 1, but exclude the the ones that also have badge (2,3,4,5)

This is what I have so far but i keep getting a syntax error on line 3

```
    SELECT bdgid, usid
    FROM member_badges
    WHERE bdgid = 3, bdgid NOT IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Comment: You can not use `,` to seperate the conditions. I think you want to use `AND` instead or `OR`

Comment: `bdgid = 3` already implies `bdgid NOT IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT bdgid, usid
FROM member_badges
WHERE bdgid = 3
AND usid NOT IN (
    SELECT usid
    FROM member_badges
    WHERE bdgid > 3)
```

Another way:

```
SELECT usid
FROM member_badges
GROUP BY usid
HAVING MAX(bdgid) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To find only badge 1:

```
SELECT bdgid, usid FROM member_badges WHERE bdgid = 1;
```

To find badges 1 to 3 and sorting by bgdid and usid:

```
SELECT bdgid, usid FROM member_badges WHERE bdgid <=3 ORDER BY bdgid ASC, usid ASC;
```